# Freemarker: creating a table with a list in a list

Tags: java, markdown, freemarker

I currently have following structure:

```
List<List<ClusterEntry>> clusters = new ArrayList<List<ClusterEntry>>();
//fill clusters and the list in clusters
input.put("clusters", clusters);
```

clusters describes my clusters and cluster.get(i) contains all the elements in one cluster. For a report I want to output this result with freemarker into a .md file The goal is to have as much columns as clusters and in each row an entry of the corresponding cluster.
The problem I am facing is, that I have to start with the outer list, meaning the clusters:

```
|<#list clusters as c>  Cluster ${c_index} | </#list>
|<#list clusters as c>-----|</#list>
```

This is my solution to make the header being in one line. If I do it like this:

```
|<#list clusters as c>  Cluster ${c_index} | 
</#list>
```

my output will be a seperate row for each Cluster ${c_index}

So now I have a column for each of the Cluster names, but how do I fill out the entrys in a corresponding row? I need the entrys of each different cluster in its corresponding seperate column, but I do not know how to achieve this with freemarker, as this code:

```
<#list clusters as c>  
<#list c as entry>| ${entry.id} |</#list> 
</#list>
```

would result in the entrys of one cluster being in one row and the next cluster in the next row. I want this but with columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, then given this input (using http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/ syntax):

```
clusters=[["a1", "b1", "c1"], ["a2"], ["a3", "b3"], ["a4", "b4", "c4"]]
maxEntities=3
```

you want this output (which I have made a bit nicer with padding... if you need that, use `?right_pad(n)`):

```
| Cluster 1 | Cluster 2 | Cluster 3 | Cluster 4 |
|---        |---        |---        |---        |
| a1        | a2        | a3        | a4        |
| b1        |           | b3        | b4        |
| c1        |           |           | c4        |
```

Well, it won't be very pretty, as you want to rotate the table in the template. But, the idea is that the outer loop goes through the entity indexes, and the inner loop goes through the clusters. (You also have two exceptional rows at the top, which shows the cluster names and the header separator line.)

```
|<#list clusters as c> Cluster ${c?counter} <#sep>|</#list>|
|<#list clusters as c>--- <#sep>|</#list>|
<#list 0 ..< maxEntities as entityIndex>
|<#list clusters as c> ${c[entityIndex]!} <#sep>|</#list>|
</#list>
```

BTW, `maxEntities` can be calculated in the template, if that's better:

```
<#function maxListItemSize items>
  <#local max = 0>
  <#list items as item>
    <#local size = item?size>
    <#if max < size>
      <#local max = size>
    </#if>
  </#list>
  <#return max>
</#function>
```

and then you had `<#list 0 ..< maxListItemSize(clusters) as entityIndex>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help again. The formating is now exactly as I was trying to achieve. However, with this output has the java object id. I would like to access for example: c[entityIndex].id! in line 4 of your solution. Sadly I recieve then: FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> c[entityIndex]  [in template "template.ftl" at line 4, column 26]

Comment: In that case you can write `(c[entityIndex].id)!`. Kind of curious syntax, but... that's how it works.

Comment: Well, that took two seconds and solved my hour long effort from before. Thank you very much for the great help!